# C function like macros: expected an expression

Tags: c, function, macros

Can someone please help me here because i have no idea what i the world is going on here
So basically this is the i am struggling with these functions

```
#define LOWCONVERT(c) (if(isupper(c) > (0) \
                   isupper(c) == (0))
```

The macro above is supposed to covert capital letters into lowercase characters

The second macro which s supposed to compare two numbers is :

```
#define COMPARISON(d,f) (if (d > f))\
                    printf("d is greater than f\n");\
                    else\
                        if (d == f)\
                    printf("d equals f\n");\
                    else\
                        if(d < f)\
                        printf("d is smaller than f\n");)
```

When i use them it gives me :
"Error: expected an expression"

Comment: BTW, if you *hate pointers* as your nickname suggests, don't code in C. Learn some higher level language like Ocaml, Haskell, Scheme, Common Lisp....

Comment: maybe `#define LOWCONVERT(c) (isupper(c) ? tolower(c) : (c))`

Comment: haha i hate pointers because they gave me hell. it took me about 3 months to understand the concept. I am going to change that nickname as soon as I can since it attracts too much attention. Thank you for answering.

Answer (score 3):

`if` is for statements, not for expressions. Left parenthesis starts an expression.

GCC enables an extension called [statement expressions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html).

You'll better use [inline functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_function). (macros are very naughty with usage like `COMPARISON(i++,t[i--])` ...)

And you should `#include <ctype.h>` and use functions like [tolower(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/tolower.3.html) or [isalpha(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isalpha.3.html)

Ask your compiler to show you the preprocessed form. With GCC, use `gcc -C -E yoursource.c > yoursource.i` then look inside `yoursource.i` with an editor or a pager (e.g. `less yoursource.i`  ...)

Don't forget to enable debugging info & all warnings in your compiler. With GCC, that means compile with `gcc -Wall -g`

Comment: WOW this website ROCKS. than you so much guys I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use statements as expressions. If you want to group multiple statements in a macro a common way is to use a `do...while` loop:

```
#define COMPARISON(d, f)                     \
    do {                                     \
        if ((d) > (f))                       \
            printf("d is greater than f\n"); \
        else if ((d) == (f))                 \
            printf("d equals f\n");          \
        else if((d) < (f))                   \
            printf("d is smaller than f\n"); \
    } while (0)
```

Also note that I put the usage of the macro arguments inside parentheses, or an argument may contain an expression that causes the comparison operation to fail.

Comment: is it possible to add a converter (%d)? inside the printf function that way instead of just showing d id greater than f it actually prints out the actual numbers

Comment: @hatepointers Of course, just do e.g. `printf("%d is smaller than %d\n", (d), (f)); \ `